# set instance variable per convention is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

The following controller private method

```
def set_promotion
  @promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
  if !current_shopkeeper.nil?
    @current_user = User.where(['email = ?', current_shopkeeper.email]).first
  end
end
```

generates the `@current_user`, but not the promotion instance variable.
In fact when inspecting the action

```
puts params[:id].class
puts @promotion
puts @current_user.id
puts Promotion.find(params[:id])
```

the values returned are

```
string
[blank_line]
16292
#<Promotion:.... >
```

even though the controller has the before_action defined, which kicks in given the current_user.id being returned

```
  before_action :set_promotion, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

the action literally required to call

```
@promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])
```

to render the proper action.

Note: this is a controller that does not normally have access to devise's current_user and thus requires its own private method.  Not sure if this impacts anything.

```
def pundit_user
  User.where(['email = ?', current_shopkeeper.email]).first
end
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: Is this working for some actions or not at all?

Comment: Apparently not at all:  the edit function does not pick up the instance variable.  the argument in the form for the instance variable is nil (or empty)

Comment: Well, the code is correct as far as I can tell. Strange things...

Comment: Yes!!  Placing the exact same strong sequence within the action itself DOES generate the instance variable.

Comment: Can you post the controller in its entirety, rather than slicing bits out of it? Impossible to see if you have an error with what you're showing us.

Comment: The show action was defined `def show \r end` It's utterly weird that part of the before_action method fires and another does not.  I had to force the call by including `@promotion = Promotion.find(params[:id])` in the show action method.